# flask-login : can't understand how it works from documentation

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

what is the use of load_user(user_id) method ? and when will it called ? In documentation it is mentioned that it is used to reload the user object from the user ID stored in the session . I don't understand from where session gets the user_id and where the method reloads the user object.And also why it needs to write in models.py file ?

During the logging we pass the user object in login_user() method so does this method add the user object in session and sets this user to current_user ?

Answer (score 3):

When a logined user returns to your website, their browser will send cookie related to your website to the server. Like other modern web framework, flask will not store the user's credential inside the cookie, but store a session ID instead. Then flask will use this session ID to lookup the database and find the correct user information and send it back to the browser. So here is the `load_user`function kicks in. `load_user` is a callback function used by the flask-login login manager. When flask needs to look up and load the user related to a specific session ID, it will call this function. This is also why it is in the model.py since it is directly related to the database.

Comment: I didn't understand use of the load_user method. During login we fetch the user from db and passed it into login_user method ? so what the load user method does ? which user it loads ? and where the method loads or return the user ?

Comment: Ye. login_user is the method you will call to let a user have a login status. Then your website will send a session ID to the user as a temporary credential for your website so the user can keep their login status for a while. The session ID is usually stored in the cookie but it can be anywhere you want. Every time the user goes back to your site, their browser will send the session ID to your server. Flask will catch the session ID and call the callback function registered by `user_loader` decorator, which is `load_user` in your case.

Comment: @SumanSana Your method will be responsible to return the correct user object to Flask so Flask can handle it correctly and validate the user.

Comment: U said a user's user_id will be stored in session after he logged out from site . now when he comes back to the site flask will load that user. Now i want to know where it loads the user and what is the use of this method in login management . For login we need to call login_user and have to pass user object to that method after authenticating the user. So what does the load_user method does and what can we do with the prev user (user returned by the load_user). As of now I didn't  write any code with the prev user. so why do i need that method ? and why it throws error for not writing ?

Comment: I just made a simple authentication system where i get the username and password input from a login form then in backend  i fetch the user object if a user is present with that username and password in db and passed the user object to login_user method otherwise throws error. So i don;t need that prev user in my system so still why i need to write that load_user method compulsory ?

Comment: @SumanSana Session is not meant to relogin a user who logged out, but to keep a login status. For example, when you switch the pages in SO, or close the tab, close the browser or even restart the computer and go back to SO again, you are still logged in since the server reads your information from the session ID. It is essential for a website with different pages and different users to run smoothly. Otherwise, users will have to login again even when they swich from one page to another since each page and request is indep the server has no clue whether the user has logged-in in the last page.

Comment: @SumanSana So it's a way for server to track the user activity in the website and keep them logged in and (probably) ensure the user does not break any permission restrictions on the website, regardless you need it or not. E.g. SO has a privilege system and the server checks the user's privilege by looking up the session ID in db and ensure correct user has correct privilege. Many times a website failed to manage the session ID and let some users have admin's privilege. This is also a way to hack into a system by retriving an admin's session. Now websites have used a csrf token to prevent it.